# How to know when the last async server call ended

Tags: ios, swift

I'm wondering what's the best approach to handle asynchronous calls in a for loop, so we know when the last call was made/ended.

The issue here is that the for loop is was faster than the server calls, so the calls will be queued and how can I ensure the last 
was made and ended?

Take the following pseudo example:

```
someData.forEach({(object) in 
    self.myFunc(object)
})

fileprivate func myFunc(object: object) {
    doesSomeServerAsyncCallWithObjectAndCompletion(object) {(success, desiredData) in 
        // HOW TO KNOW HERE THAT THIS WAS THE LAST CALL REQUESTED??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DispatchGroup

```
 let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

 dispatchGroup.enter()
   longRunningFunction { dispatchGroup.leave() }

dispatchGroup.enter()
 longRunningFunctionTwo { dispatchGroup.leave() }

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
  print("Both functions complete ")
}
```

For example

```
   let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.allaboutswift.dispatchgroup", attributes: .concurrent, target: .global())
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    group.enter()
    queue.async (group: group) {
        print("doing stuff again 1")
        group.leave()
    }

    group.enter()
    queue.async (group: group) {
        print("doing more stuff again 2 ")
        sleep(3)
        group.leave()
    }
    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print("done doing stuff again 3")
    }
```

Comment: I'll give a try with your example

Comment: Worked as expected. Thank you.